# mongoDB, ajax, php to only display new messages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mongodb

It might be a silly question, but I think it will be useful for all new mongoDB users and not just myself.

I am currently working on a live chat script as a way to learn about mongoDB. I am having trouble with only loading new messages into chat rather than loading all messages and replacing old ones. This is what I have.

My PHP:

```
try 
{
    $m = new Mongo(); // connect
    $db = $m->selectDB("local");
}
catch ( MongoConnectionException $e ) 
{
    echo '<p>Couldn\'t connect to mongodb, is the "mongo" process running?</p>';
    exit();
}
$collection = $db->selectCollection("message");
echo "".$collection." selected";
$cursor = $collection->find();
// iterate cursor to display title of documents
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
echo $document["sender"].": ". $document["message"] . "<br>";
```

My JS:

```
function get_new(){
    var messages = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/receive.php",
        async: false
    }).success(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){get_new();}, 10000);
    }).responseText;

    $('div.messages').html(messages);
    }
```

My messages collection:

```
"createdAt" => $now, 
"sender" => $sender, 
"message" => $message
```

I know that my JS would eventually start using .append(messages), but I really don't know what to do with my PHP. So how do I change my php to only find new messages (older than last set of messages)

Comment: So you're question is?

Comment: @davejal my question is how do I change my php to only find new messages (older than last set of messages)

Comment: Why not get the last 5 or 10 messages using a query? and only displaying those?

Comment: @davejal because is this case I will lose all messages between the last set and those last 5 or 10 messages.

Comment: Well logic here would dictate that if your messages are stored by date then just ask for those newer than the last message date the client has in the request and pass that through to the query. But you also might be better served by having the server "push" on a websocket connection from a [tailable cursor](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) result, rather than have the client periodically look for "new messages". But it depends on what you really want to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Use sessions to store the time of last update. So The PHP code will look like this:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$last = $_SESSION["last_message_ts"];
$session_last = new MongoDate(strtotime($last));
$session_now = new MongoDate(strtotime($now));
$_SESSION["last_message_ts"]=$now;

 try 
    {
        $m = new Mongo(); // connect
        $db = $m->selectDB("local");
    }
    catch ( MongoConnectionException $e ) 
    {
        echo '<p>Couldn\'t connect to mongodb, is the "mongo" process running?</p>';
        exit();
    }
    $collection = $db->selectCollection("message");
    $cursor = $collection->find(array("createdAt" => array('$gt' => $session_last, '$lte' => $session_now)));
    // iterate cursor to display title of documents
    foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    echo $document["sender"].": ". $document["message"];
}
```